# How to add image zoom-in effect to block without fixed size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have fluid grid: 3 blocks in one row with `width:33.3%`. Images witch contain in this block have `width: 100%` and `height: auto`. I want to add zoom-in effect on hover for this images. But I have no ideas how to do it with fluid grid and without changing blocks height. You can see my code snippet below.

Any ideas how to solve it?

```css
.split.third {
  width: 33.3%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.split.third img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.split.third:hover img {
  width: 120%;
}
```

```html
<div class="split-wrap">
  <div class="split third">
    <div class="cover">
      <img src="http://cs5-3.4pda.to/5290239.png" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="split third">
    <div class="cover">
      <img src="http://cs5-3.4pda.to/5290239.png" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="split third">
    <div class="cover">
      <img src="http://cs5-3.4pda.to/5290239.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `transform: scale(1.2)`.

```css
.split.third {
    width: 33.3%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.split.third img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease;
            transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease;
            transition: transform 1s ease;
            transition: transform 1s ease, -webkit-transform 1s ease;
}
.split.third:hover img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
            transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="split-wrap">
  <div class="split third">
    <div class="cover">
      <img src="http://cs5-3.4pda.to/5290239.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="split third">
    <div class="cover">
      <img src="http://cs5-3.4pda.to/5290239.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="split third">
    <div class="cover">
      <img src="http://cs5-3.4pda.to/5290239.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But i don't need to change blocks size

Comment: Then leave the `overflow`. *This* is the correct answer.

Comment: Ok. Add overflow: hidden ;)

Comment: Yeah, guys. `overflow: hidden` and `transform: scale(1.2)` works for me. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @AlexanderSeredenko If answer was helpful could you mark it as correct?

Comment: @3rdthemagical Sure, I'll do it. Now I can't, I need to wait and in few minutes I'll do it

Comment: @AlexanderSeredenko Thank you!